# What is the Microsoft authentication scheme for ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication

I'm setting up a [social sign-in provider authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/social-without-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2) with a Microsoft authentication. The linked tutorial uses Google as an example and provides the code to get its authentication scheme for the `DefaultChallengeScheme`.

What is the authentication scheme for Microsoft? I've been unable to find it.

My Startup.cs > ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //set up using this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/social-without-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2
    services
        .AddAuthentication(authenticationOptions =>
        {
            authenticationOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            authenticationOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = //??? what goes here
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
        {
            microsoftOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
            microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
        });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

Comment: Most likely possibility: `authenticationOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;`  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal value used for the authentication scheme is `Microsoft`. You can access this value using the constant `MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`:

```
authenticationOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = 
    MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```

Here's the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/MicrosoftAccount/src/MicrosoftAccountDefaults.cs#L8) for the constant:

> ```
> public static class MicrosoftAccountDefaults
> {
>     public const string AuthenticationScheme = "Microsoft";
>
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Comment: Does it use cookie-based authentication under the hood? I mean, once user gets validated, how the state is persisted in MVC application? Though, I looked into the code but did not find any implementation for this Context.SignInAsync() for Microsoft auth scheme.